# What are those labels called that have a person's name in offices?

Tags: word-request

Is there a specific term for the labels used in offices and other places, which are mounted outside a person's office or cubicle and carry his name and other details?

Comment: A [_nameplate_](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/nameplate)

Comment: When placed around a conference table, they're known as _toblerones_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I've never heard that before (in the US or UK), but I like it :). For those that don't get the reference, a **toblerone** is a swiss chcolate bar in a triangular shape (http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=toblerone&tbm=isch)

Comment: @Matt. I remember a cartoon in which a delegate to an international conference was desperately looking through an atlas on seeing a genuine bar of Toblerone chocolate next to where he was sitting. It would be indelicate of me to give his nationality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to "nameplate", the term **plaque** /plak/ refers to an object affixed to a wall, door, or other surface that has an inscription or decoration on it. It is often used to identify or commemorate somebody or something.

A door plaque would be affixed to an office door and might have the name and title of the person who occupies the office. It might also identify the room. (For example "Conference Room A" or "Engineering Dept".)

A wall plaque, mounted to a wall near the door, can serve the same purpose.

Q. Are  you the head of security?
A. That's what the plaque on the door says.

Answer (score 2):

While *toblerones* has been mentioned (cited in comments without references) as meaning nameplates around a conference table, the term  *[place card](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/place_card#Noun)* or possibly *name card* is more likely to be used in that context.  A place card is “A card set down at a table to inform a guest where they are to sit”.

*[Nameplate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nameplate#Noun)* has already been mentioned.  A *nameplate* is “A plate or plaque inscribed with a person's name, especially one on an office door”.

An alternative to *nameplate* as an office label is *[doorplate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doorplate)*, “A plaque mounted on a door bearing information about the occupant or a room or building”.

Two more terms occasionally (but rarely) used for this purpose are:
• *[escutcheon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escutcheon)*, of which OED1 says “3. Anything shaped like, or resembling, an escutcheon: ... c. A key-hole plate, a name plate, etc.”
• *[placard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/placard#Noun)*, “A sheet of paper or cardboard with a written or printed announcement on one side for display in a public place”.

Answer (score 1):

Those labels are called [nameplates](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/nameplate); when they are placed around a conference table, they're known as *toblerones*<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> reference needed

<sub>*Note: this answer is based on the comments by [Bill Franke](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4848/what-are-those-labels-called-that-have-persons-name-in-offices#comment6781_4848) and [Barrie England](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4848/what-are-those-labels-called-that-have-persons-name-in-offices#comment6782_4848).*</sub>

Comment: No offence! but is it a copy of the comments above?

Comment: @Thor, yes, I posted this answer as a CW, though. The fact is that Bill's and Barrie's comments impede to anyone to post an answer whitout beaking the etiquette.  But in this kind of cases CW answers are good.

Comment: ... oh, etiquette says: avoid plagiarism.

Comment: You can turn anyone's comments into an answer because the comments are under the [cc-by-sa](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) license.  You *do* have to give credit, but you don't need permission.

Comment: @snailplane: Just because you can do so *legally* doesn't mean that doing so is polite. In future, I think it would be better to invite the commenters to post their comment as an answer - that way they have the opportunity to keep the rep if they so choose, and the post is clearly attributed to them.